# Within Salesforce1 Canvas App, Redirect to a page of the Parent Salesforce1 App

Tags: visualforce, canvas

I guess what I'm trying to do is impossible but I want to get your expert opinion before giving up. I've searched for an answer but found nothing.

Here's what I have: I have created a Canvas App called by a Visual Force page. In the Canvas App, I display a list of leads. For the moment this is a list of  HTML tags that redirects to https:/[instance].salesforce.com?id=[id] which works great when accessing the Canvas App from the Desktop version of Salesforce.

Here's what I would like: when the user is accessing the Canvas App from within Salesforce1, instead of redirecting the user to https:/[instance].salesforce.com?id=[id] (which is not user friendly at all since it redirects to the non-responsive salesforce desktop version) I'd like to redirect the user to the Salesforce1 App specific Lead page (which is user-friendly for mobiles but not an HTML page anymore I guess).

Is there any way I can do that using the JS SDK for instance ?

Any suggestion would help me in my quest.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Quentin

Answer (score 0):

The question dates one year earlier but it is worth giving the answer for future
developers,
to redirect to the parent container just use:

> top.location = 'your location';